# How to split a tree view in two columns in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Got a single column with a lot of fields and want to split it. What event should i use? Tried `<separator string="Links" colspan="4"/>` but just splits it in half.

Comment: Provide more details and include the code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Just have to add to:

```
<group>...</group>
```

this:

```
<group col="4">...</group>
```